# How to set the data path of an action driver?

Tags: scripting

I need to take the frametime of the second keyframe of a parameter as a driver ,so I use the driven system, this is my driver's expression:
but I don't know how to write the datapath of the action.I searched this site,no one had asked about the data path of the action,I am confused....any one can help me ,thank you very much!
[image]

[image]